# Filtering an HTML list based on InnerText of child elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML list `<ul>` with many `<li>` elements like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="talent.aspx">Talent Map</a></li>
  <li><a href="assets.aspx">Assets Map</a></li>
  <li><a href="know.aspx">Knowledge Gaps</a></li>
  ... This is a pretty long list
</ul>
```

I have a text box at top of the list where user can type in a few characters to filter the list with matching text inside `<a>`. In the above example, if the user types 'map', the list should be filtered for the first two items.

Currently, I have created a hard-coded JavaScript collection object with text and anchor links for the entire menu. On filtering, I hide the original menu and recreate links from the matching items in link collection object. But this does not appear the right approach to me.

Comment: Please post the relevant js code and html with textbox markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#your_text_box').keyup(function(){
var valThis = $(this).val();
$('ul>li>a').each(function(){
 var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    (text.indexOf(valThis) == 0) ? $(this).show() :    $(this).hide();         
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML code**

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li><a href="talent.aspx">Talent Map</a></li>
    <li><a href="assets.aspx">Assets Map</a></li>
    <li><a href="know.aspx">Knowledge Gaps</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS code**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myList li").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by jquery like this...

```
$('input').on("change",function(){
    var filter_text = $(this).text();
    $('ul>li').each(function(){
        if($(this).text().indexOf(filter_text) > -1){
            $(this).show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Note: This is a simple jquery filter based on text value...

Comment: Should the 'filter_text' inside indexOf be without single quote?